# How to turn for loop into a math equation?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I have the following two loops in my program and I am trying to write them out as math equations, but I'm having some difficulty finding a concise way to do so:

```
// Loop1
for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    array[i] = nepr;
}

// Loop2
for (int i = 0; i < (nvr % nr); i++) {
    array[i]++;
}
```

The code is completely function, but I'm trying to express these loops in a document I'm writing.

> Any help would be very much appreciated.

So far I have this:

```
array[i] = nepr, i = 0,...,(nr-1)
```

but I'm not sure how to incorporate the second loop into the equation, or write a second equation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear that's what you are asking, but the following does the same thing in a single loop.

```
for (int i = 0, j = nvr % nr; i < nr; i++) {
    array[i] = nepr + (i < j);
}
```

---

[EDIT] In casual language without any loops the above is equivalent to...

> Let `j = nvr % nr`. Assuming positive `nr` and `nvr`, `0 <= j < nr` and:
>
> - `array[i] = nepr + 1` for `i = 0 ... j-1`
> - `array[i] = nepr` for `i = j ... nr-1`

Comment: Thanks actually, I think I can do this:    array[i] = nepr + (i < j); i = 0,...,(nr-1); j = nvr % nr

Comment: Assuming positive is needed. Code does fail with `nvr = 7; nr = -3;`

Comment: @chux Right. I edited the answer to spell out the positiveness assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Just express it as a [piecewise-defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise):

```
 f(x) = {nepr + 1 if x <  (nvr % xr)}  
        {nepr     if x >= (nvr % xr)}
```

You can also define it in terms of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function):

```
 f(x) = nepr + H((nxr % xr) - x)
```

Comment: I believe your notation doesn't take into account that x is discretely valued. Your equations are for x being continuous. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Veridian That's not directly necessary, the equations are still valid.  If you want to express that x must be an integer, just state it separately.

Comment: @chux It seems likely that nvr is always positive, but I changed it anyway.

Comment: Yes, assuming `nvr, nr` positive does simplify the problem.  Doubt if OP wants a full range `int` solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop, the condition check has the `nr-1` as abound.

If i understood your problem correctly, you can express it like

> `array[i] = array[i] + 1 , i = nvr % nr ,...,(nr-2)`

Comment: The dependency on nvr is missing

Comment: @Veridian what kind of dependency? Ultimately you're going to use `nvr % nr` value, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in LaTeX. To see or edit the LaTeX, click on the equation.

[image: latex equation]

The `:=` symbol expresses assignment. You could also write it in functional fashion by replacing `array_i` with `array(i)`, a function defined on an open range of integers.

Comment: Probably you should add i ∈ N

Comment: @Logman that seems inherent in the fact that i is used as an index into array

Comment: @GuyGreer but let's stay formal ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would try to post a full `int` range soukltion base on [@dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230874/2410359) fine answer which works well when `nr, nvr` are positive - the usual case.

Assume `nr, nvr` are `int`.

```
assert(nr != 0);
assert(nr != -1 || nvr >= -INT_MAX);  // avoid -2147483648 % -1
int j = nvr % nr;
int ij = max(i,j);
for (int i = 0; i < ij; i++) {
    array[i] = nepr + (i < j);
}
```